# how to scroll page to the center of accordion content?

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar, zurb-foundation, accordion

When using the accordion from Zurb's Foundation 5, it makes the scroll bar jump when the class of "active" is applied to show the content. This causes the video to show up partially cutoff. I would like to scroll the window so that the "active" div is in the center of the viewport. This way the video is always centered when navigating through the accordion. Any advice and help is much appreciated. Example at http://rmaguns.com/shoot-guns.html. Scroll all the way to the very last accordion (explosive targets) and click it. When it opens it shows the video partially cut off. Any advice on how to center the video in the viewport would make my day!

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and you may be able to adapt this to work.
You will need to put this inside your :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('.active').click(function() {
    var viewportWidth = jQuery(window).width(),
        viewportHeight = jQuery(window).height(),
        $foo = jQuery('#foo'),
        elWidth = $foo.width(),
        elHeight = $foo.height(),
        elOffset = $foo.offset();
    jQuery(window)
        .scrollTop(elOffset.top + (elHeight/2) - (viewportHeight/2))
        .scrollLeft(elOffset.left + (elWidth/2) - (viewportWidth/2));
});

});
```